# Magento 2 : Difference between Magento 2.1.1 and Magento 2.1.2?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, version, magento-2.1.2

Magento 2 has released the new community edition version `2.1.2`. I  am very curious to know the **difference with previous Magento edition** ?

I want to know the full detail of the new feature introduced in new Magento version `2.1.2`.

Also want to know if is there any bug(pending or new) with the latest version `2.1.2`.

> Did anyone encounter any problems or bugs after upgrade/install new version of Magento `2.1.2` ?

Comment: what exactly stops you from reading its release notes????

Answer (score 2):

> Magento CE 2.1.2 Release Notes
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.2CE.html

Release note is the best place to find whats fixed, what changed and what is new. the whole purpose of release note is to let others know what new/changed/fixed.

If you want to know what is fixed follow the links in release note that start with `(GITHUB-XXXX)` eg ([GITHUB-6424](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6424)) which elaborate on the bug that was initially there and is now fixed.

If you want to go little deep with Magento's Progress check out **Magento's github issue page** to find more about new bugs and what isues are closed

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if we should take a look at the release note: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.2CE.html

Comment: Except the release note I wanted the know what are the new features/changes we have with new version. Also want to know about the possible bugs in magento 2.1.2